# Jasmine's exclude/focus operations cause exit status 1

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli

I have Karma running Jasmine tests. I run these using `npm` scripts which, ultimately, use Angular CLI's `ng test`.

When I try to use `xdescribe`, `xit`, `fdescribe`, or `fit`, my tests run as expected, but I see an error.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! {my package@version} test-watch: `ng test`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the {my package@version} test-watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

`npm` complains loudly about the error. `ng test` doesn't complain, but fails to go into a watch. I assume `ng` is also aborting because of the exit status.

Is this failed exit by design? Is it up to the reporter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a failed coverage threshold. Obviously, excluding some or nearly all specs or suites greatly affected the coverage.